# Why do we need the axiom MS3 for localizing categories?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, derived-categories

> **Background:** Let $\mathsf{C}$ be a category and $S$ be a collection of morphisms (let's suppose that $S$ has all the identities and is closed under multiplication just to simplify a bit). We can construct the *localization* $S^{-1}\mathsf{C}$ as a category such that $\operatorname{Ob}(S^{-1}\mathsf{C})=\operatorname{Ob}(\mathsf{C})$ and such that a morphism is an equivalence class of *strings* of the form $s_0^{-1}\circ f_1\circ s_2^{-1}\circ f_3\circ \cdots\circ f_n$, where we impose all the obvious compatibility conditions such as $s^{-1}\circ s\sim\operatorname{id}$. (These compatibility conditions can be found on the page 2 of [Dragan Milicic notes](http://www.math.utah.edu/%7Emilicic/Eprints/dercat.pdf).)

One problem with localization in all its generality (as described above) is that if $\mathsf{C}$ is an additive category, it is not clear if $S^{-1}\mathsf{C}$ is also additive or not. For that, we impose the axiom "LMS2":

[image]

This implies that every morphism in the localization can be represented as $s^{-1}\circ f$ and that any finite number of morphisms can be represented using the same "denominator" $s$. In particular, we can define an additive structure on $S^{-1}\mathsf{C}$ as
$$s^{-1}\circ f + s^{-1}\circ g=s^{-1}\circ (f+g).$$

In basically every reference that I could find, the authors also required an axiom "LMS3" given by

[image]

I feel like this last axiom is only useful for giving a simpler (is it really simpler?) description of the equivalence relation between morphisms without needing to ever consider strings of length larger than 2.

**Is there a real need for this axiom LMS3 that I didn't see?**

Comment: If C is a small category, and $S \subseteq Mor C$ is _any_ set of morphisms, there _always_ exists a small category $S^{-1}C$ and a functor $C \to S^{-1} C$ which universally forces the morphisms of $S$ to become invertible. Likewise, if $C$ is a small additive category and $S \subseteq Mor C$, there is always a small additive category $S^{-1}_{add} C$ universally inverting the morphisms of $S$. So in some sense, there is no "real need" for _any requirements whatsoever_ on $S$, without further clarification of what one's "real needs" are.

Comment: @TimCampion firstly, I didn't know that a localization of an additive category is always additive. Do you have some reference for that? Anyway, I think that "having a simple structure for the sum of morphisms on the localization" is a good motivation for considering the axiom LMS2. But I don't really see what we gain with the axiom LMS3.

Comment: I don't claim that $S^{-1} C = S^{-1}_{add} C$ in general.

Comment: @TimCampion so you mean that $S^{-1}_{add}C$ is universal among only the additive functors, but not all functors. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Cool! I'm still interested in a reference for that and in my original question, though.

Comment: One way to see that $S^{-1}C$ and $S^{-1}_{add} C$ exist is to invoke the adjoint functor theorem. I guess what I'm driving at, though, is that your original question (the bolded text) is ambiguous: if all you want out of the localization is its defining universal property, then you don't "really need" anything at all. So it seems to me that one should first ask the preliminary question "What does one 'really need' out of a localization construction?". One property often considered desirable is that $S$ should be _saturated_, i.e. that no morphism not in $S$ become invertible in $S^{-1}C$.

Comment: A related discussion about the construction of the additive localization by closing $S$ under finite sums: https://mathoverflow.net/q/44047/1017

Comment: @TimCampion When we consider some axiom, we hope to gain something from it, don't we? That's my question. It is clear to me why someone would consider the other axioms or saturated classes. The axiom LMS3 is not as clear.

Comment: @Gabriel Axioms of the form LMS3 are part of the notion of calculus of fractions. They ensure that the localization will have as many finite (co)limits as $C$. This kind of axiom is not necessary to understand localizations and only gives useful sufficient conditions ensuring the localization is well behaved.

Comment: One commonly-used term for this sort of condition is "right Ore condition". See also the [nlab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/calculus+of+fractions). The point is well-taken -- it would be valuable to explicitly spell out exactly what is achieved by such conditions.

Comment: @Denis-CharlesCisinski I would be very glad if you could explain more your point. For example, how exactly is the localization "better behaved" when we suppose this axiom? I don't quite understand how this relates to (co)limits.

Comment: @TimCampion as you actually know, I'm writing my own notes on the subject, so I assure you that I've read all the presentations of localization of categories that I could find haha. And none explained why this axiom is important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The axiom LMS3 you ask about directly corresponds to the axiom that any parallel pair of arrows in a filtered category can be coequalised.
The idea is to consider the full subcategory of $\mathcal{C}_{/ N}$ spanned by the $(L', s')$ where $s' : L' \to N$ is in $\mathcal{S}$, which by a minor abuse of notation I will denote by $\mathcal{S}_{/ N}$.
(If $\mathcal{S}$ has the 2-out-of-3 property and contains all identity morphisms then this is no abuse of notation.)

Given an object $(L', s')$ in $\mathcal{S}_{/ N}$ and a morphism $h : L' \to P$ in $\mathcal{C}$, we have a morphism $h \circ (s')^{-1} : N \to P$ in $\mathcal{C} [\mathcal{S}^{-1}]$.
This defines a cocone from the obvious diagram of shape $(\mathcal{S}_{/ N})^\textrm{op}$ to $\mathcal{C} [\mathcal{S}^{-1}] (N, P)$, and hence a map
$$\varinjlim_{(L', s') : (\mathcal{S}_{/ N})^\textrm{op}} \mathcal{C} (L', P) \to \mathcal{C} [\mathcal{S}^{-1}] (N, P)$$
When you have a Gabriel–Zisman calculus of fractions, $(\mathcal{S}_{/ N})^\textrm{op}$ is filtered and the comparison map is a bijection.
Filtered colimits have many convenient properties and in this situation we are able to easily transfer convenient properties of $\mathcal{C}$ – e.g. existence of finite limits and/or colimits – to $\mathcal{C} [\mathcal{S}^{-1}]$.